# Including css and js file in wordpress does not work on localhost

Tags: php, wordpress

I don't see any issue but I think the problem is I am using localhost

```
<?php 

function styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('fontawesome-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.min.css');
}
function scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.js', array(), false, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), false, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('main-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array(), false, true);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'styles');
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'scripts');
```

Comment: Two things: 1. You could merge `styles()` and `scripts()` into a single function; 2. Check that your theme has the `wp_head()` function in header.php.

Comment: founded wp_head() in header.php

Comment: Try naming your functions something *unique* (eg. `function my_theme_prefix_styles() { /*rest of the code */ }`). This is a practice you should follow always to avoid name collisions: [WordPress - Best Practices - Prefix Everything](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/best-practices/#prefix-everything).

Comment: Nothing happend

Comment: Where are you adding this code?

Comment: on my code 
i changed name of my two function

Comment: first my_theme_prefix_styles
last my_theme_prefix_scripts

Comment: and i changed add_action too

Comment: What I meant to ask was: are these two functions inside your theme's functions.php file?

Comment: yes in functions.php exist 2 function

Comment: can i upload my folder and send link to you ?

Comment: Edit your question and add a minimal version of your theme here (include index.php, header.php, footer.php, functions.php) so we can reproduce the problem (see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more details).